# How can I get checkins in a certain location on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

I guess the title is pretty self-explanatory. I want to get all the checkins in a certain area given the latitude and longitude.

All I've been able to find is `https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/recent` and `https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues`, but neither of them are useful for me.

I'm pretty sure there has to be a way, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this api and filter by `"hereNow"` count for each venue, this will give you count of people currently in that location

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
```

more details here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Comment: Maybe I was not explicit in my initial post, so sorry for misleading you. What I am looking for is a way to get the last N checkins in a certain location, no matter when they did it. So I don't necessarily want the current checkins, I am actually looking for the history.

Comment: you can only get checked-in user list from a place via API only if you are also checked-in at that place. Couple years ago you were able to get currently checked-in users even if you were not checked-in, but foursquare stopped giving that data.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer because as far as my research goes, this is the most you can get from foursquare at the moment.

Comment: how can i find my current checkin by using API?