# Foursquare API returns zero checkinsCount check-in counts in Python, but returns non-zero value in online trial interface

Tags: python, foursquare, checkin

I use the following code to get details of a venue (with venue ID: 412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3) in my local PyCharm Edu:

```
import json, requests
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'
CLIENT_ID = 'XYZ' # I replace "XYZ" using my real CLIENT ID
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XYZ' # I replace "XYZ" using my real CLIENT SECRET
id='412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3'
params = dict(
  client_id=CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
  v='20180323'
)
resp = requests.get(url=url+id, params=params)
data = json.loads(resp.text)
with open('resp_detail.json', 'a') as the_file:
    dumped=json.dumps(data)
    the_file.write("%s\n" % dumped)
```

The returned checkin statistics are: 
`"stats": {
"tipCount": 1672, 
"usersCount": 0, 
"checkinsCount": 0, 
"visitsCount": 0}`.

However, when I use the online trial interface (https://foursquare.com/developers/explore#req=venues%2F49eeaf08f964a52078681fe3%3F) to get details of a venue for the same venue ID, the return results are:
`"stats": {
"tipCount": 389
"usersCount": 16762
"checkinsCount": 25938
"visitsCount": 32866
}`

The online results should be correct since this venue is Central Park, New York and it should get lots of checkins. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Foursquare even didn't post a sample code for "get details of a venue".

Could anyone help to correct my code? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning on May 31st, foursquare made five changes in order to simplify their API and maintain the quality of their service as their developer community grows.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/announcements#start-up-tier-launch

> Access to check-in counts, visit counts, chain details, and key tastes will be removed

So you can not get `checkinsCount`. I think the online trial interface is exception.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is a disaster. So do you know which APP can provide `checkinsCount` like Foursquare did?

Comment: Sorry I googled APP can provide checkinsCount , but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare gives the number of check-ins for a venue under **beenHere** element, only if you have already checked-in on that venue before.

You can see the question;
[How can I get checkins in a certain location on Foursquare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390776/how-can-i-get-checkins-in-a-certain-location-on-foursquare?rq=1)